# VBA code: "select rows to delete except headers" (not working)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which should simply select a range of rows and delete them. Unfortunately it deletes the headers as well, no matter how I change the range.

I tried to change the "rng" parameter without success.

Thank you for the feedback you can provide.

```
Sub delete_rows_range()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng, Rng_del As Range
Dim leg As Range

Set leg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("aB1")
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b1")

If Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = True Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If
rng.Select

rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=leg

'rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete
rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select

Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Use This line `Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(2).Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a single cell as the range.

When you `.Offset` a single cell range, then use `xlCelTypeVisible.EntireRow.Delete

Excel selects every cell on the sheet and deletes them.

You really should clarify your range with a properly defined range object. e.g.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:AB" & lRow)
```

But if you want to use `B1` as your `rng` you can replace your line, `rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select` with this line...

```
rng.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Hi GMalc, thank you for your explanation and your time.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select from a single cell range.

You should do instead:

```
Sub delete_rows_range()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng, Rng_del As Range
Dim leg As Range

Set leg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB1")
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")

If Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

rng.Select

rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=leg

'rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete

Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(2).Select

Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!